# Windows explorer fast to open across network, but slow on the host machine

Tags: windows-xp, windows-explorer

Apologies if this has been asked elsewhere - I can find plenty of "fast local, slow across network" references, but none regarding the opposite.

I have a machine running Windows XP SP3 ("Remote") and two other ("Local") machines either running Windows XP SP3 or Windows 7. I have a shared folder on the Remote machine. The folder is jam-packed with folders of images, and there is also a folder ("Zips") jam-packed with zip files for each of the other folders.

If I access the shared folder across the network, it is fast to open, fast to open the zips folder, and fast to copy a new zip file into it. This applies regardless of whether I do this from the Win XP SP3 machine or the Win 7 machine.

However, if I walk to the remote machine and open Windows Explorer, when I navigate to the shared folder (or worse, to the Zips folder), it takes a near eternity (ie minutes) to open the folders. During this time, Task manager process view shows that explorer.exe is almost always consuming 100% of the available CPU time (actually 25% of available, but it's a quad-core machine).

As yet I have found no windows settings that make a difference, nor any clue as to what could be taking all that time. Help?